# Firefox not executing JavaScript files that were loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm trying to load two scripts that were functionally deferred on account of their `type` attributes being non-standard i.e. `text/javascript/defer`. Doing this causes the parser to ignore them so I want to reload them using JavaScript.

My HTML is as below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>No Title</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script type="text/javascript/defer" src="assets/js/test3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript/defer" src="assets/js/test4.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var defer_js_collection_obj = $("[type='text/javascript/defer']"),
            el_head_rq_obj = $('head'),
            el_head_obj = el_head_rq_obj[0]
        ;

        if(defer_js_collection_obj.length > 0)
        {
            //Reload JavaScript
            defer_js_collection_obj.each(function() {

                var file_src_outer_html_str = this.outerHTML;
                var file_src_res_arr = file_src_outer_html_str.match("src *\= *[\"\']{1}(.*?)[\"\']{1}");
                var file_src_str = file_src_res_arr[1];

                var fileref = document.createElement('script');
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                fileref.setAttribute("src", file_src_str);
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
            });

            //Unload JavaScript with defer tag
            for(var j = defer_js_collection_obj.length-1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                defer_js_collection_obj[j].parentNode.removeChild(defer_js_collection_obj[j]);
            }
        }

    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div>Load Deferred JavaScript</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`jquery.js` is version 1.11.2. `test3.js` and `test4.js` reference the javascript files I want to load, and they contain `console.log('test3.js is loaded');` and `console.log('test4.js is loaded');` respectively.

The issue I'm having is that this script works virtually everywhere else except on Firefox. I'm on a Mac OS X 10.10.5 using Firefox 46.0.1, and I don't see the `console.log` message when I load the script.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `text/javascript/defer` is an invalid *type*. To *defer* JS you need to use the *defer* attribute another way: `<script defer type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/test3.js"></script>` Hacking/altering native functionality will make your code difficult to maintain. In HTML5, you can safely omit the script type anyway, so `<script defer src="assets/js/test3.js"></script>` would work just fine as `text/javascript` is the default.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with that, but I prefer doing it this way because of better overall browser support. It works on all the browsers I've tested it in, but not on Firefox so I'm trying to find out why.

Comment: Have you considered that Firefox simply does not like the malformed `type` of `text/javascript/defer`? I just ran a quick test using `type="text/javascript/defer"` for a simple JS file, and it does not work in FF, but it works in Chrome. Looks like FF just doesn't like it.. nor should it.

Comment: `text/javascript/defer` is not going to work because the parser will ignore it on account of it being non-standard syntax: no browser likes it. This is why I'm using the JavaScript code in the question to reload it into the `<head>` using the standard `text/javascript` type attribute, which should work in every browser.

Comment: Try wrapping your code in an IIFE: `(function($) { // code }(jQuery));` (instead of `$(document).ready(function(){ // code });`) The DOM ready might be throwing a wrench in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a mime type issue.  Do you happen to see any message in the console stating "not well-formed"?  In any case, this seemed to work for me and I agree that your code did not work in FF when I first tried it.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("main");

        var $body = $($("body")[0]);
        var $scripts = $("[type='text/javascript/defer']");

        $scripts.each(function(){
            var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
            scriptTag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            scriptTag.setAttribute("src", $(this).attr("src"));
            $body.append(scriptTag);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't see anything in the console stating "not well-formed". I updated the script and it seems to be working now, but I'm not sure why. I might have to introduce a firefox filter to run your script if the browser is firefox.

Comment: I'm also getting this warning in the console: `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/`

Answer (score 1):

Try to append your **script** at the end of **body**, so instead do:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that but it didn't work. I see the scripts before the closing body tag but no `console.log` message.

Comment: Use Firefox Inspectors, to see what your code exactly affect in the page!

Comment: As I mentioned above, the code is a simple `console.log` message, nothing else.